# Hide shortcut keyboard bar for UIWebView in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview

I'm developing PhoneGap application for iOS and I need to get rid of new iOS 9 shortcut bar. Now I'm doing the following in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` method

```
if ([self.webView respondsToSelector:@selector(inputAssistantItem)]) {
    UITextInputAssistantItem *inputAssistantItem = [self.webView inputAssistantItem];
    inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
    inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
}
```

This hides undo/redo and copy/paste buttons but shortcut bar still presented on keyboard and has navigation buttons on it.

[image]

How can I get rid of shortcut bar completely.

Thanks for your help!

******* **UPDATE 1** *******
My full working code is below. Hope this can help someone (thanks to @Clement reply)

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

- (void) hideKeyboardShortcutBar: (UIView *)view
{
    for (UIView *sub in view.subviews) {
        [self hideKeyboardShortcutBar:sub];
        if ([NSStringFromClass([sub class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebBrowserView"]) {

            Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(sub.class, @selector(inputAccessoryView));
            IMP newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _s) {
                if ([sub respondsToSelector:@selector(inputAssistantItem)]) {
                    UITextInputAssistantItem *inputAssistantItem = [sub inputAssistantItem];
                    inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
                    inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
                }
                return nil;
            });
            method_setImplementation(method, newImp);

        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self hideKeyboardShortcutBar:self.webView];
}
```

This trick will hide undo/redo and navigation buttons. But auto-prediction text still will be shown on keyboard. To hide shortcut bar completely add html attributes to your input element

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" />
```

P.S My app is on the review now. Still don't know if Apple will approve this.

******* **UPDATE 2** *******
My app was approved by Apple

Comment: You can't, is part of the web view. Phonegap/Cordova is just using HTML to builds its you ui and then it is presented in a web view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, rckoenes. But why I still able to hide undo/copy/paste buttons?

Comment: try not putting the input fields inside a form

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, not putting the input inside a form does not help.

Comment: @rubanbs, which class did you put your code? I tried putting it in the MainViewController.m, and it doesn't work.  The breakpoint hits and the code steps through fine.  However, the do and undo still show and work in my keyboard.

Comment: @CaptainSkubalon see my full code in question's update

Comment: @rubanbs, Thank you for the update.  My compiler did not understand the Method key word, but when I commented out the lines that dealt with that variable, I got my desired results.  Since I am not an Objective C programmer, that's good enough for me.  :)

Comment: @CaptainSkubalon add this import `#import <objc/runtime.h>` at the beginning of file. This can fix your error.

Comment: @rubanbs,  thanks again. That did the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using method swiziling we can remove the keyboard shortcut bar (only works with ObjC).

```
 - (void)hideKeyboardShortcutBar
    {
        Class webBrowserClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIWebBrowserView");
        Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(webBrowserClass, @selector(inputAccessoryView));

        IMP newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _s) {
            if ([self.webView respondsToSelector:@selector(inputAssistantItem)]) {
                UITextInputAssistantItem *inputAssistantItem = [self.webView inputAssistantItem];
                inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
                inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
            }
            return nil;
        });

        method_setImplementation(method, newImp);
    }
```

> **inputAccessoryView**
>   : This property is typically used to attach an accessory view to the
>   system-supplied keyboard that is presented for UITextField and
>   UITextView objects.

So the new implementation block will be fired every time the keyboard pops up.

**UPDATE**

To remove the accessory view from `WKWebView` use `WKContentView` instead of `UIWebBrowserView`

Comment: This works! Thanks. Do you think if Apple will approve this?

Comment: Yes it is approved by apple.

Comment: I'm curious if anyone has been rejected for this? The Telerik keyboard plugin removed this feature because "it used a so-called 'private API' which Apple is now rejecting when your app is reviewed". http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/keyboard