# How to hide shortcut bar in iOS9 UIWebview?

Tags: uiwebview, ios9

I would like to hide bar which is on top of keyboard (undo, redo, copy and back, forward buttons) when user clicks on textfield in **UIWebView**.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Put in the css file :
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Disable selection/copy in UIWebView */
}

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to hide that bar.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743649/hide-shortcut-keyboard-bar-for-uiwebview-in-ios-9

Answer (score 1):

Using method swiziling we can remove the keyboard shortcut bar (only works with ObjC).

```
 - (void)hideKeyboardShortcutBar
    {
        Class webBrowserClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIWebBrowserView");
        Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(webBrowserClass, @selector(inputAccessoryView));

        IMP newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _s) {
            if ([self.webView respondsToSelector:@selector(inputAssistantItem)]) {
                UITextInputAssistantItem *inputAssistantItem = [self.webView inputAssistantItem];
                inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
                inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
            }
            return nil;
        });

        method_setImplementation(method, newImp);
    }
```

> **inputAccessoryView**
>   : This property is typically used to attach an accessory view to the
>   system-supplied keyboard that is presented for UITextField and
>   UITextView objects.

So the new implementation block will be fired every time the keyboard pops up.

I posted this answer in [Hide shortcut keyboard bar for UIWebView in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743649/hide-shortcut-keyboard-bar-for-uiwebview-in-ios-9/33017695#33017695) as well

Answer (score 0):

I am able to hide those using these lines

```
        let item:UITextInputAssistantItem = self.textFieldName.inputAssistantItem
        item.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
        item.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I don't have a textfield. It's a Webview ;-)